# Check SQL query like enum in MySQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, check-constraint

In MySQL I'm using `enum` and display variable with `enum_range`. 
How can I display check variable range in SQL Server if

```
roles VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (roles IN('Admin', 'Staff', 'User'))
```

Comment: Just google *sql server check example*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the values, don't use either `enum` or `check`.  Use foreign key constraints:

```
create table Roles (
    RoleId int identity primary key,
    RoleName varchar(255)
);

insert into Roles(RoleName)
    values ('Admin'), ('Staff'), ('User');

create table . . . (
    . . .
    RoleId int references Roles(RoleId),
    . . .
);
```

The shortcuts you want to use just get in the way of using the capabilities of the database.